# java- making a path more dense?

Tags: java, geometry

I have an array list of points in JAVA.
I want to add more points so the path is more dense.
How should I try to do this?

I made this image to explain better

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are thinking abount interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider two points from your 2D-polyline A (x1, y1) and B (x2, y2).

We can build straight-line equation using these two points `A` and `B`.

The common form of the equation is: `y = k*x + b`, where `k` and `b` are constants.

Using `A` and `B` coords we build an equation system:

```
k*x1 + b = y1
k*x2 + b = y2
```

Solving this equation we get `k` and `b` constants and therefore we have the line equation built.

After that, substitute `X` coordinates to this equation and you get `Y` coordinates.

So, we need to find dots between A and B.

And we substitute `x1 + 1` as `X` to this equation, to get relevant `Y` coordinate.

After that we substitute `x1 + 2` as `X` to this equation to get the relevant `Y` coordinate and so on, until you get `X2` coordinate of the dot `B`.

---

Consider the following example.

We have `A (2, 2)` and `B (5, 3)`

Building the equation system:

```
2 * k + b = 2
5 * k + b = 3


b = 2 - 2 * k
5 * k + 2 - 2 * k = 3
3 * k + 2 = 3
3 * k = 1
k = 1/3

b = 2 - 2/3
b = 4/3
```

and our A-B line equation is:

```
y = x/3 + 4/3
```

let's find dots *between* `A` and `B`.

We increase x coordinate of the dot A to 1, and are going to find Y coordinate of that dot.

```
x = 3
y = 1 + 4/3 = 7/3
```

Now, get the next dot after that, using `x = 4`

```
x = 4
y = 4/3 + 4/3 = 8/3
```

Dot `B` has x coordinate equal to 5, just checking:

```
x = 5
y = 5/3 + 4/3 = 3

correct!
```

That's it.